# Give a specific user permissions to a specific folder from root

Tags: linux, permissions, subdirectory, chmod, user-permissions

I want to give specific users permissions to specific folders, with different levels of permissions (Read, Write, Execute) in Linux. And to do the same for some groups.

For example I want to give the user: `sigmundlucas` permissions (Read, Write) for `promotional_material`

Another example is that I want to give the group: `testers` permissions (execute) for `development_project_data_directory`

I need to do all of this from the root account as the folders in question don't allow permission to use `chmod` when signed into the user

I need to add that multiple groups/users need to access some of the files

Answer (score 0):

This is normally accomplished with `chown` and groups!

Make some groups for you users to be members of

Then `chown` the directory to be `:<group>`

For example

```sh
groupadd mygroup                 # create a new group
usermod -aG mygroup myuser       # add the group to the user's info
chown :mygroup target_directory  # set the group to own the directory
chmod 770 target_directory       # root and the group can enter/read/write
```

You can calculate the chmod with a website like https://chmod-calculator.com/ if you're not used to the numbers

Gotchas

- directories need to be executable to be entered
- users must be able to *read* all the intermediate paths to somewhere you want them to be able to *write*